# Installing Ruby 1.9.3 in Ubuntu giving errors

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I had to do a lot of juggling when I tried to install Ruby 1.9.3, and it is mentioned in community that `ruby1.9.1` is the package to be installed for Ruby 1.9.3. Now, if i run `ruby`, I get

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': 
        cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

What can I do?

FYI, I uninstalled everything in my comp by `sudo apt-get remove --purge ruby1.8 libruby1.8`

Then I installed Ruby1.9.1 by `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 libruby1.9.1`

What do i do?

**EDIT**:

After the comments, I used rvm to install newer ruby 1.9.3, ANd now everything is perfect.

**MORAL**:

*dont* use apt-get for ruby. Use rvm, gem and other ruby tools. It's brilliant.

Comment: You would likely get better results with a more descriptive title.

Comment: 1.9.1 is kind of old.  You might consider trying 1.9.3, for other reasons, if you can switch to it, and that might fix this problem as well.

Comment: I edited the question - I wanted to switch to 1.9.3. And ubuntu community says ruby1.9.1 is the package to be installed for ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: You could try compiling Ruby directly instead of using a package--it's not too hard.  Check out  https://rvm.io/rvm/install/.

Comment: Please, please, don't use `apt-get` for installing ruby. Use rvm. Check out Eric Walker's link.

Comment: Okay, I chucked apt-get. Doing using rvm.

Comment: Yes! "installing X (including version #) in Y gives errors" is a far better title than "X does not work".

Comment: will keep in mind. @SunnyJuneja, It's solved. rvm works like crazy! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Ruby system-wide with `apt` then the latest RubyGems won't be included in the install. Ruby is the language, RubyGems is the package manager which has to be installed separately.

To install RubyGems just go [here](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) and follow the instructions:

> 1. Download from above.
> 2. Unpack into a directory and cd there
> 3. Install with: **`ruby setup.rb`** (you may need admin/root privilege)
> 4. For more details and other options, see: **`ruby setup.rb --help`**

Comment: I've already done that. The problem is `ruby` itself is not working. And that somehow seems to be because I used `apt-get`. I'm trying to install `ruby` using `rvm` now.